# max of different classes in pivot table pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataset as following

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2020, 'Jan', 1],
                   [2020, 'Jan', 2],
                   [2020, 'Jan', 3],
                   [2020, 'Feb', 4],
                   [2020, 'Feb', 5],
                   [2020, 'Feb', 6],
                   [2021, 'Jan', 7],
                   [2021, 'Jan', 8],
                   [2021, 'Jan', 9],
                   [2021, 'Feb', 10],
                   [2021, 'Feb', 11],
                   [2021, 'Feb', 12],
                   [2022, 'Jan', 13],
                   [2022, 'Jan', 14],
                   [2022, 'Jan', 15],
                   [2022, 'Feb', 16],
                   [2022, 'Feb', 17],
                   [2022, 'Feb', 18]],               
                   columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Sale ($)'])
```

which shows the sales of different months and years.

Using [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) function, I can create a pivot table to calculate sum of sales for different months and years.

```
df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Year', aggfunc='sum')
```

And that generates a summary statistics table as following:

|  | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 6 | 24 | 42 |
| Feb | 15 | 33 | 51 |

Here is my question: How can I identify the month at which in each year I had the highest sale?

I know that for the years 2020, 2021, and 2022, my highest sales were 15, 33, and $ 51 respectively.

I can achieve this by adding .max() into the end of the code

```
df.pivot_table(index='Month', columns='Year',aggfunc='sum').max()
```

and this returns exactly that:

| Year | Sale |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 15 |
| 2021 | 33 |
| 2022 | 51 |

And in the case of this example, the maximum sales were all in February so how can I write a function that returns not the maximum value, but the month which had the maximum sale?

Comment: `idxmax` instead of `max` -> `df.idxmax(axis = 0)` ??

Comment: Yes! This also allows me to change the axis and find the year in which a certain month had the highest sale, thank you!